# Is there a way to increase `find` speed

Tags: find

I am wondering is there a way to increase `find` speed in terminal, it doesn't make sense that using internet google to search will have a better speed than doing a local search for strings or just file names.

I am wondering is there a way to have a local indexing base, once built, in the future, the find command could be super fast.

Or any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your post with your operating system and/or distribution?

Comment: `it doesn't make sense that using internet google to search will have a better speed ` what a weird thing to say. Filesystems aren't optimized for `find`, but Google very much is, likely for example with super optimized hashmaps to do bag of words related search, and huge maximum inner product search engines for dense neural representations

Answer (score 15):

Try using `locate`, it should do what you want.

Comment: Its usually a good idea to flesh out the answer a bit more. Like mentioning what package `locate` comes from (usually `slocate`), and to use `updatedb` for rebuilding the DB. :-)

Comment: This does not work for partitions with indexing turned off. E.g. NTFS partitions suffer from bad performance if indexing is enabled, thus locate won't work for those "as it should".

Answer (score 14):

It depends much on what your search criterion is.

If you search for filenames or filename patterns, locate is much faster, but not suitable for freshly generated files, since the index used is normally updated only once per day. But if you can use it, it is super fast.

But with find you can search for file size, file age and other things, which aren't searchable by locate.

If you know **where** to search, you can use the **path** to delimit the search scope:

```
find /some/path -size -10M -size +2M -mtime -365 ...
```

would only search files from 2 to 10 M, maximum 1 year old in /some/path.

Programs, available in the path can be searched by *which*; help, lib and configuration files with *whereis*. Examples:

```
which java
/usr/bin/java

whereis firefox 
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /etc/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /usr/share/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
```

If you execute programs on every file you find with -exec, -execdir, -ok or -okdir, which is available in GNU-find for example, you can pass multiple files at once to the program, if the program supports being called with multiple arguments, by ending your command with "+" instead of ";". Example:

```
find -name "*.pdf" -exec ls -l {} "+"
```

This can speed up the whole process significantly, but depends much on individual circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

Use `locate`

The reason is that `locate` uses a database of all the existing directories and files that's **already been built** just like you imagined!
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_locatedb.htm

At some set (and changeable) interval, a job runs does scans the file system and then builds a database with it.  It is then this database (locatedb), with its appropriate indexes that the `locate` command goes against instead of scanning through your hard drive at that point.

So the upside is that it's *very* fast in comparison to a hard drive scan.  The downside is that the locate database (locatedb) is not 'live' so can only be used for files that existed 'as of' the last scan.

To update locatedb now run `updatedb` (or `sudo updatedb` if necessary)

btw I just ran `sudo updatedb` locally and it took 3 1/2 seconds!  I have 31,000 files.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, locate may be a better tool for simpler searcher.

However, for more complex searches you're probably stuck with find.

One way to speed up find is to narrow down which directory your files are in instead of searching all of the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

for a single search operation; I didn't find any speedup; unless trying to narrow down the search using `find` options.

However; if you want to do **multiple `find` operations on the same set of files**; I got a significant speedup populating a temporary file with all the filenames and using `grep`. Of course this does not take into account files that are added or deleted.